# Рекомендации по улучшению кода

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

```
class Loader
{
    public DataSet _data = null;
    public int _streamRecordCount = 0;
    public int _fileRecordCount = 0;
    public int _dbRecordCount = 0;
    public Loader()
    {
        _data = new DataSet();
    }
    public DataSet Data { get { return _data; } }
    public void LoadFromStream(string path)
    {
        Stream stream = new Stream();
        _data.Add(stream.ReadFromStream(path, out _streamRecordCount));
        stream.Close();
    }
    public void LoadFromFile(string path)
    {
        File file = new File();
        _data.Add(file.Read(path, out _fileRecordCount));
        file.Close();
    }
    public void LoadFromDatabase(string connectionString)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.Connect(connectionString);
        _data.Add(db.LoadData(out _dbRecordCount));
        db.Close();
    }
    public string GetResult()
    {
        return "Stream: " + _streamRecordCount.ToString() + "; File: " + _fileRecordCount.ToString() + "; Database: " + _dbRecordCount.ToString() + ";";
    }
}
```

Comment: в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: @teran Нужно отрефакторить код

Comment: методы, которые выгружают из базы или из файла я бы сделал с возвращаемым значением, чтобы не было `loader.LoadFromDatabase();
var data = loader._data;`

Comment: Существует специальный сайт системы для подобных вопросов: http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Зачем нужен GetResult() , если public int _streamRecordCount = 0;  открыт для {get;set;}

Comment: @FoggyFinder На сколько я знаю, [на Stack Overflow на русском допустимы вопросы инспекции–кода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо за информацию

Answer (score 4):

В первую очередь я бы очень рекомендовал вмиесто повсеместного использования `Close` использовать `using` или же оборачивать работу с файлами, потоками и базами данных в блок `try` с освобождением ресурсов в блоке `finally` так как в случае возникновения исключения метод `Close` может быть не вызван, что способно привести к неприятным последствиям

Answer (score 4):

Вот это не круто

```
return "Stream: " + _streamRecordCount.ToString() + "; File: " + _fileRecordCount.ToString() + "; Database: " + _dbRecordCount.ToString() + ";";
```

C# до 6 версии, но актуально и в 6ой

```
return string.Format("Stream: {0}; File: {1}; Database: {2};"
   , _streamRecordCount, _fileRecordCount, _dbRecordCount);
```

C# с 6 версии

```
return $"Stream: {_streamRecordCount}; File: {_fileRecordCount}; Database: {_dbRecordCount};"
```

Comment: `string.Format` чудовищно медленный. Потому что строка формата разбирается в рантайме. Интерполированные строки основаны тоже на нём. Конкатенация строк, как бы её ни ругали, реально быстрей (я бы только `ToString` убрал). Хотя, конечно, это экономия на спичках.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я не думаю, что подобная оптимизация уместна в приведённом на инспекцию коде. И разве StringBuilder не быстрей?

Comment: `StringBuilder` ради объединения полудюжины строчек - это из пушки по воробьям. И слишком громоздко. Но если код выполняется в цикле много раз, то, конечно, используем его.